# Digital Image Processing

Tags: education, image-processing

I'm a Computer Science Graduate but I didn't study digital image processing during my college years. Now I'm thinking of learning it, but I'm little bit confused about where to start.

Is there any short series of undergrad-level lectures that I can follow, combined with any hands-on mini project (like processing and identifying nudity in an image), so that I can apply my learning?

Comment: Do you mean course with video or just text[book]? (There's no shortage of the latter...)

Comment: For the former https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVV0TvNK6pk&list=PL1F076D1A98071E24

Comment: @RespawnedFluff Text Book will take lot of time. I just need 'Undergrad' introductory material. Video lecture would be more preferable.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff The link that you gave has 40 Lectures equivalent to reading a book. Is there any other 8-10 lecture series.

Comment: Also identifying real-world objects in an image is not considered image processing much but rather [computer vision](http://szeliski.org/Book/). I suppose if you only want to solve a particular problem, you can be more selective with your reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these lectures from Tufts University. I read some of the slides where the basics are explained and how to use MatLab to apply them. I think they are easy to follow.

Even if you don't have MatLab, you can learn pretty much from them and use other tools to do your projects.

Here are some of the topics you can find on the slides:

- Images representation
- Image file formats
- Basics of MatLab (focused on images)
- Image enhancement
- Region processing and convolution
- Edge filtering
- Image segmentation
- Geometric transformations

The link: [EN 74-ECE: Processing and Analysis of Multidimensional Signals Fall 2007](http://www.ece.tufts.edu/en/74/)

Comment: Obviously, summarizing a whole lecture course would be too much to ask. But you should at least indicate what major topic areas are covered.

Comment: You are right David, I added some of the topics I found in the lectures.

Answer (score 0):

Check this course from Northwestern University :

Fundamentals of Digital Image and Video Processing.

The link to view the contents: https://www.coursera.org/learn/digital